# Sitecore ExperienceForms 10.3 does not have IFormFieldConverter interface

Tags: sitecore-forms

We are facing some issue in Sitecore Experience Forms 10.3.

We upgraded the project from 9.2 to 10.3 XP and we have done some customization in Sitecore ExperienceForms functionality. `IFormFieldConverter` will convert the `formSubmitContext` fields then we are adding it to the custom token.

Sitecore ExperienceForms 10.3 does not have `IFormFieldConverter` interface but in earlier versions like Sitecore Experience Forms 9.2 have the `IFormFieldConverter` interface.

Any alternate solution/approach/suggestion for this?

Comment: what is customization are you doing?

Answer (score 1):

**IFormFieldConverter** was part of the **Sitecore-Forms-Extensions** and not of **Sitecore Forms** code:

https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/blob/feature/9.2/src/Feature/FormsExtensions/code/Business/FormFieldConverter.cs
https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/blob/feature/9.2/src/Feature/FormsExtensions/code/Business/IFormFieldConverter.cs

You need to bring this code into 10.3.
In Sitecore it exist IFormFieldDataConverter but it's something different than the code of Sitecore-Forms-Extensions